# JavaFX 8 WebView: Is not a valid win32 application

Tags: java, webview, javafx-8, targetinvocationexception, java-8

**Main**:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

**View** :

```
<code>StackPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"><br/>
  WebView fx:id="webView" /> </StackPane></code>
```

**Controller**:

```
<br/>
 @FXML<br/>
    private  WebView webView;<br/>
    @Override<br/>
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {<br/>
    }
```

Os: I 'm using Windows 8.1 x64 Preview (Blue)

The program was fail to start, Internet explorer 11 is enabled, this simple program was worked before 1 week, what happens and it crashes with these errors ? 
The problem is on line 12 (this line shows the **WebView** tag)  
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\jfxwebkit.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Could the file have been truncated or corrputed?

Comment: I unistall jdk8 and jre8 and i re-install them... the problem exists :/

Comment: Which build of JDK8 you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jdk8 x86 build, not the x64.

Comment: Finnaly I role back to jdk7u40 x64. I'm waiting for official final release  of jdk8... anyway thanks !